# When all solutions of $y''+ay'+by=0$ are bounded in R?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Could you please help me solve this problem.

Suppose $y''+ay'+by=0$ is differential equation with $a,b$ are real numbers.
I need to find conditions when all solutions of this equation are bounded.

I managed to establish that in case of $a^2-4b \ge 0$ we can found a not bounded solution,
and in case of two pure imaginary roots of characteristic equation all solutions of given equation are bounded.

But I have a difficulty to deal with the case of two complex roots of characteristic equation
$\lambda_1=\alpha+i\beta,\lambda_2=\alpha-i\beta$:

If $\frac {\alpha}{\beta}\ge 1$ we can found a not bounded solution, but what can we do if $\frac {\alpha}{\beta}< 1$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Bounded for $t\ge 0$ or for $t\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: The answerers (save for Amitai) appear to have worked on the DE
$$y''+ay'+by=0.$$ If that was what you intended, please edit the question.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry about a initial mistake,thank you all for your kind answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer.

If what you are asking is boundedness of ALL the solutions of your ODE, for $t\ge 0$, then the answer is:
$$
a\ge 0\quad\text{and}\quad b>0,
$$
or
$$
a> 0\quad\text{and}\quad b=0,
$$

If what you are asking is boundedness of ALL the solutions, for $t\in \mathbb R$, then the answer is:
$$
a= 0\quad\text{and}\quad b>0.
$$

Explanation. If $b<0$, then the equation $\lambda^2+a\lambda+b=0$ has a positive and negative root, say $r,-s$, and in such case $e^{rt}$ is a non bounded  solution.

If $b=0$, then for $a=0$, the general solution is $c_1t+c_2$, unbounded, while for $a\ne 0$, the general solution is $c_1+c_2e^{-at}$, also unbounded.

If $b>0$, and $a\ne 0$, we have to consider two cases: real roots and complex roots. In both cases we find an unbounded root.

If $b>0$ and $a=0$, then the general solution is $c_1\cos(\sqrt{b}\,t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{b}\,t)$, which is of course bounded.

Comment: I asked about boundedness of all the solutions for $t\in R$. Could you please give me some hint how to prove this ?

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the equation in question? Or did you read $b$ as $by$?

Comment: I made mistake, my equation is $y''+ay'+by=0$, but never mind, I learned something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The boundedness of the solutions depends on the sign of the real part of the roots of the characteristic equation.